# I cannot get php bcrypt to work and I don't know why

Tags: php, bcrypt

I've been upgrading my script to use bcrypt for authentication and I cannot get it to work. Here's some sample code I have.

```
<?php
require '../functions/config.php.inc';
if ($_POST[login]) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $typedpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($info);
    $storedpass = $data['password'];

    //this code block is for stack overflow (it saves the entered password into a bcrypt hash then fetches the database row)
    $darealhash = password_hash($typedpass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
    $result5 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$darealhash' WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    $info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($info);
    $storedpass = $data['password'];
    print_r($data);echo "<hr>";
    echo "darealhash is $darealhash // storedpass is $storedpass // username is $username<br>";

    if(password_verify("$typedpass", $storedpass)){
        echo "correct password";
    } else {
        echo "WRONG password!"; 
    }
}
?>
<form method="POST">
  <table border="0">
  <tr>
  <td>
  Username: <br><input type="text" size="15" class="bigtext" maxlength="25" name="username">
  </td>
  </tr><tr>
  <td>
  Password: <br><input type="password" size="15" class="bigtext"  maxlength="25" name="password">
  </td>
</tr>
 <tr><td align="right">  <input type="submit" name="login" class="bigbutton"  value="Login"></td></tr>

  </table></form>
</body>

</html>
```

What the code above does is save whatever password is being used in the login form to the database in a bcrypt hash, then the bcrypt hash in the database is compared against the plaintext enter of the password, and if correct it echoes "correct password" but it keeps echoing "wrong password" and I don't know why.

Comment: After `<?php` add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and check the errors. Also please stop using deprecated `mysql_*` , use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: I can use this class to get all the `mysql_` functions to work once everyone upgrades to php 7. http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9199-PHP-Replace-mysql-functions-using-the-mysqli-extension.html The only error displaying is `Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead`

Comment: yes, that's why i said move to  `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. because `mysql_*` is deprecated in php5 version and removed in php 7.

Comment: did you try to echo these variables `$typedpass`  `$storedpass` ?

Comment: Yes I did echo those two variables. $typedpass is whatever I typed in and $storedpass is the same as $darealhash and they both match the password field in the user's database row.

Comment: I've fixed the problem now.